# How to get two many2one fields from single class?

Tags: python, odoo

I have following code I want this two fields asset_catg_id and folio_num. These should be available for many2one two fields. How to write 2 _rec_name for a single class?

```
class asset_asset(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "asset.asset"
    #_name = "asset_asset"
    _rec_name= "folio_num"
    #_rec_name = "assetmodelid_add"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Asset Name', size=64),
        'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
        #'place1': fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation', 'Location'),
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True),
            'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name', 'Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',domain="[('area_id', '=', area_id)]",),
        'folio_num' : fields.char('Folio No',),
        'asse_line':fields.one2many('asset.line','emp_id','Name Plate'),
        'asse_line2':fields.one2many('asset.part','emp_id1','Parts'),
               #'assed_modelid':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model ID',select=True, required=True),
        'quantity': fields.char('Quantity',size=64),
        'uom': fields.char('Uinit of Measure',size=64),
        'model_no' : fields.char('Model', size=64),

        #'asset_id':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Asset ID'),

    }
```

Comment: i want two many2one fields how to get it

Answer (score 0):

In this case we will override name_get() method module

```python
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    if not len(ids):
        return []

    res=[]

    for assest in self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context):
        res.append((assest.id, assest.asset_catg_id + ', ' + assest.folio_num))     

    return res
```

Comment: i mean i am going to get 2 fields as many2one in other class or modules  . in your case its concatenating to one field

Answer (score 0):

if u want to show asset category name to _rec_name in asset.asset ok 
**so create fileds like:**

```
'folio_num': fields.related('asset_catg_id', 'name', type="char", string="Folio Name"),
```

if u want to like display name so create compute fileds it' batter

Comment: but its getting rec_name of that class

Comment: _rec_name= "folio_num" ???/

Comment: _rec_name = 'asset_catg_id' try it

Comment: i want both fields folio_num and asset_catg_id

Comment: batter u use display_name compute fields and retun concate "asset_catg_id+folio_num" this is best 4 u .....

Comment: Other wise you can use name_get ()..............

Comment: please help me how ? shridharivani@gmail.com its my mail id ping me i will send you dependent module and with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

many2one field by default displays either name field or the field which is defined in _rec_name. If you want to display value of other fields then you need to override name_get method in your object.

For example I want to display two fields (name, name2) in my many2one field:

```
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not len(ids):
        return []
    res = [(r['id'], r['name'] and '%s [%s]' % (r['name'], r['name2']) or r['name'] ) for r in self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['name', 'name2'], context=context) ]
    return res
```

You may refer: [ORM Method: name_get.](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.name_get)

Comment: good work dear.......